# How to do a recursively method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a recursive method to find.

But I don't understand why it finds the element but returns undefined.

How can solve it, please?

Here is my code:

```
export const findDmaFromHierarchy = (hierarchy: [], value: string): any => {
  let founded = undefined;
  hierarchy.forEach((dma: any) => {
    if (dma.children) {
      findDmaFromHierarchy(dma.children, value);
    }
    if (String(dma.value) === String(value)) {
      console.log("founded: ", dma);
      founded = Object.assign({}, dma);
      return founded;
    }
  });
  return founded;
};
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: you can't return from `.forEach`, use vanilla `for` loop

Comment: because you don't get any value from ` findDmaFromHierarchy(dma.children, value);` and founded stay unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set `founded` when the recursive call finds the value.

```
export const findDmaFromHierarchy = (hierarchy: [], value: string): any => {
  let founded = undefined;
  hierarchy.forEach((dma: any) => {
    if (dma.children) {
      founded = findDmaFromHierarchy(dma.children, value);
      if (founded) {
        return founded;
      }
    }
    if (String(dma.value) === String(value)) {
      console.log("founded: ", dma);
      founded = Object.assign({}, dma);
      return founded;
    }
  });
  return founded;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take `Array#some` and return early on found.

Then I suggest to check if the value is found and assign the object and return with true. To move this check in front of the function omits unnecessary checks for `children` objects.

For children take a temporary variable and check it and assign and return if truthy.

```
export const findDmaFromHierarchy = (hierarchy: [], value: string): any => {
  let found = undefined;
  hierarchy.some((dma: any) => {
    if (String(dma.value) === String(value)) {
      console.log("founded: ", dma);
      found = Object.assign({}, dma);
      return true;
    }

    if (dma.children) {
      let temp = findDmaFromHierarchy(dma.children, value);
      if (temp) {
          found = temp;
          return tru;
      }
    }
  });
  return found;
};
```